# Datepicker getting misplaced in a popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I am using the `jQuery datepicker` for an input field on  popup.

Now the problem that I am facing is that the dynamically generated node for the `datepicker` is getting attached to the body which is wrong.

it should be getting attached to the popup.

This way the popup is getting wrongly placed based upon the height of the body and not the popup.

Can anyone guide me on what to do in such situations?

Regards,
Sourabh.

Comment: please change z-index of your datepicker div

Comment: the one that's dynamically generating? Can you please explain me the logic behind such reasoning? :)

Comment: becuase your datepicker div z-index is less than that of your modal so it will be behind that ,so need to give high z-index that the popup to appear it on popup

Comment: I have changed the z-index of the datepicker div to 999999999 but no change. :(

Comment: please create a fiddle or update your code here

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the popupContainer value

> $(el).datepick({popupContainer: '#modal'})

Where **modal** is your id of popup element

This is referenced to [jQuery Datepicker](http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html)

Comment: No there is no such option as popupContainer in datepicker provided by jquery ui.

Comment: Sorry my bad, I thought you are using this [jquery date picker](http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html). Though you can try this one. if you like

Answer (score 0):

As I was certain that the problem lied with the attachment of the generated datepicker division to the body and not the popup, I had to figure out that I would have to do something that could curb the offset generated with every scroll. So what I did was to override the position fixed for the datepicker div with

```
.ui-datepicker{
  position : absolute !important;
}
```

Now I could use the offset of the input element and add the height of the input element everytime the popup is generated. Something like:

```
var dpTopOffset = $("input#whateverId").offset().top + $("input#whateverId").height();
```

And use this to set the offset top of the datepicker on beforeShowEvent with the following code:

```
$("input.datePick").datepicker({
   beforeShow: function(input, inst){
      $(inst).offset({top: dpTopOffset});
   }
});
```

Though this is a kind of hack but this works for me!! :)